# T-SQL concatenate & convert string to date time

Tags: sql-server, datetime, concatenation

I have a table (once again implemented by the bio-metric software) that stores date and time as strings in different columns.

Date column stores date like `20160128` for `January 18 2016` and the time column stores the time like `220747` (`10:07:47 PM`).

How I can concatenate both the strings and convert to a valid datetime value?

I have referred few of the other questions asked here already and found many of them only refers to the date part, missing time factor

[image: Table structure]

Comment: What are the **datatypes** for these columns?

Comment: As I mentioned with the post, the values are stored as strings. Both columns are defined as char

Comment: You really mean `CHAR(XXX)`, or `VARCHAR(XXX)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can manipulate the strings into a format SQL server can natively parse, you can then just cast it - e.g. yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss format:

```
declare @date char(8)
set @date = '20160128'

declare @time char(6)
set @time = '220747'


select cast(@date + ' ' + substring(@time, 1, 2) + ':' + substring(@time, 3, 2) + ':' + substring(@time, 5, 2) as datetime)
```

Comment: I'm accepting your suggestion as answer as I have no other goes visible as an immediate solution for my requirement. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The following is an example script that converts from a date and time stored in `VARCHAR` columns. If formatted as `YYYYMMDD[ hh:mm:ss[.mmm]]` (ISO 8601 format) this can be cast to a [`DATETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx):

```
DECLARE @dtpart VARCHAR(16) = '20160128';
DECLARE @timepart VARCHAR(16) = '220747';

SELECT 
    CAST(@dtpart+' '+LEFT(@timepart,LEN(@timepart)-4)+':'+SUBSTRING(@timepart,LEN(@timepart)-3,2)+':'+RIGHT(@timepart,2) AS DATETIME)
```

---

If your date/time strings are stored in `CHAR` columns it's a little more involved as strings are padded with spaces. This requires trimming the spaces using `RTRIM`:

```
DECLARE @dtpart CHAR(16) = '20160128';
DECLARE @timepart CHAR(16) = '20747';

SELECT CAST(RTRIM(@dtpart) + ' ' + LEFT(RTRIM(@timepart),LEN(RTRIM(@timepart))-4)+ ':' + SUBSTRING(RTRIM(@timepart),LEN(RTRIM(@timepart))-3,2) + ':'+RIGHT(RTRIM(@timepart),2) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the help pages of `Convert` and see what best fits your needs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

```
SELECT Convert(datetime, '20160128' + ' ' +  '22:07:47', 113)
```

seems to work, so I'd suggest you simply concatenate the date as is and *enrich* the time part as needed (using `SubString()`, take care to add a starting zero when the hour part has only 1 number)

Comment: your answer looks the most feasible, however as I mentioned with my question, the time string is 220747, and to bring your suggestion to a working solution, I have to do additional string manipulations to format it like 22:07:47. It is much simpler with Oracle...

Comment: I think the problem is not so much with the RDBMS but rather with the application that stores a datetime as a string =) It's both inefficient (takes more space) and makes working with the values a lot harder (e.g. try to calculate the time-difference between 2 records) Maybe Oracle has an implicit conversion that supports this format but even then it remains a questionable design-choice as it still needs to do the conversion over and over again to the 'native' datetime data-type whenever you want to operate on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
declare @val varchar(10) = '20160128'
declare @va2 varchar(10) = '220747'

select convert(datetime,cast(convert(date, @val, 121) as varchar(10)) +' '+substring(cast(@va2 as varchar (6)), 1, 2)+':'+substring(cast(@va2 as varchar(6)), 3, 2)+':'+substring(cast(@va2 as varchar(6)), 5, 2))  as Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
DECLARE @dtpart VARCHAR(16) = '20160128';
DECLARE @timepart VARCHAR(16) = '220747';

DECLARE @t DateTIME  
SET @t = LEFT(@timepart,LEN(@timepart)-4)+':'+SUBSTRING(@timepart,LEN(@timepart)-3,2)+':'+RIGHT(@timepart,2) 

select LEFT(convert(varchar(50),Convert(datetime, @dtpart ,100)),11)+' '+ LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), @t, 22), 11))
```